# Can ReSharper live templates do conditional code generation?

Tags: resharper, live-templates

Example: I would like to have a template that inserts a method. If the class is declared `sealed`, then I'd like the method to be declared `private`. If the class is not `sealed`, then I'd like the method to be declared `protected virtual`.

Another example. If the class is inherited, and the superclass contains a method `X`, then call `base.X();` otherwise do nothing.

Is this type of conditional processing available in ReSharper? I guess this is getting close to T4 territory but it would be really handy to be able to do this in Live Templates.

In case it matters, I'm using R# 7.

### Detailed scenario

Both of these requirements came from trying to write a Live Template for the IDisposable pattern (see [Implementing the Disposable Pattern Correctly](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P)). The generated code needs to be different depending on whether the class is a base class or subclass. One can define two templates, but it is not difficult to dream up other scenarios where this would be useful. Here's the code in my IDisposable template:

```
#region IDisposable Pattern
    /// <summary>
    ///   Finalizes this instance (called prior to garbage collection by the CLR)
    /// </summary>
    ~$ClassName$() {
    Dispose(fromUserCode: false);
    }

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(fromUserCode: true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

private bool disposed = false;

// Declare as private if this class is sealed.
protected virtual void Dispose(bool fromUserCode)
{
    if (!disposed)
    {
        if (fromUserCode)
        {
            // ToDo - Dispose managed resources (call Dispose() on any owned objects).
            // Do not dispose of any objects that may be referenced elsewhere.
        }

        // ToDo - Release unmanaged resources here, if necessary.
    }
    disposed = true;

    // ToDo: Call the base class's Dispose(Boolean) method, if available.
    // base.Dispose(fromUserCode);
}
#endregion
```

Comment: I don't see the point of `sealed` `protected`.  Sealed classes cannot be inherited, so `protected` is pointless.  Might as well be `private`.

Comment: Agreed - it was a typo. Should have been private. Already updated. But this was just a contrived example anyway, don't interpret it too literally. I just want to know if there is a way to do things conditionally in R# live templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly do this. What you need is a plugin that implements the corresponding [live template macro](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/4.04+Live+Template+Macros+%28R7%29) that performs the actual check.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri - a simple unequivocal answer. Like it.